# Build libcurl with SSL for embeded device

Tags: linux, ssl, curl

I am building firmware for a device like modem. It base on linux kernel. I must build libcurl with SSL but I have some troubles.
In my virtual machine, when I build curl from source code, I just type:
./configure
make
sudo make install
And it run perfected with SSL support.

Compiler:         gcc
  SSL support:      enabled (OpenSSL)
  SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
  zlib support:     enabled

When I build curl with firmware, I still use same command and result after commnad ./configure is:
SSL support:      no      (--with-{ssl,gnutls,nss,polarssl,cyassl,axtls,winssl,darwinssl} )

What is different in two cases? In Ubuntu, I have already installed openssl, I think I must build curl in fireware with --with-openssl=/path/to/ssl/so/file but It's didn't effect, result still SSL suport no.

Can you help me? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to cross compile OpenSSL for the platform you're building libcurl for.

What you're doing is trying to use x86 version of libssl installed on your system, which won't work for an obvious reasons.

Comment: I have already build OpenSSL in my platform. Should I copy it and special path to it when run ./configure --with-ssl?